# Parsing a function of type string and return a tuple with a value of int and str

Tags: python

I am stuck on understanding this. string to return tuple.

I need a function,

```
def a (b):

to parse a string, lets say "35 age 6 ft" and parse it into a tuple of type(s) int, str, int string (35, "age", 6, "ft")
```

I am lost on how to do this. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you show anything you have done?

Comment: You can start with https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html

Comment: you can use `tuple("35 age 6 ft".split())`

Comment: Are you expecting a specific pattern of integer and non-integer parts in the input? If yes, what should happen if the pattern is violated? Or do you just want to find every sequence of digits? Do you need to handle negative numbers as well? What about positive integers prefixed with `+`?

Comment: @Shijith You statement will return 35 and 6 as a string value :-)

Answer (score 2):

To not be dependent on the input size use list comprehensions and convert the result list to tuple

```
def a(b):
    return tuple(int(x) if x.isdigit() else x for x in b.split(' '))
```

There isn't a clear cut solution to check if a string is `int` or `float`, so you can build helper function to check it

```
def check_string(s):
    try:
        return int(s) # the value is int
    except ValueError:
        try:
            return float(s) # the value is float
        except ValueError:
            return s # the value is not a number

def a(b):
    return tuple(check_string(x) for x in b.split(' '))
```

Comment: This seems to be the most concise and most idiomatic expression for the given problem

Comment: What if its a float? is there a way to just return the number regardless of int or float

Comment: @NewPythonCoder You can use `float(x)` instead of `int(x)`, but it will add .0 to ints.

Comment: I meant I just realized that the strongs can be (35.0 word) or (35 word). So if its set to return int, it has an error for the float.  Is there an if statement for 'if int' or anything? Or a return numerical number regardless of int or float

Comment: @Guy No if you use ```float``` in your code instead of ```int``` its of no use. If I pass ```"35.5"``` it will give output as ```'35.5'``` and not ```35.5```

Answer (score -2):

You can try this:

```
def a(b):
    val = b.split()
    return (int(val[0]) if "." not in val[0] else float(val[0]), str(val[1]), int(val[2]) if "." not in val[2] else float(val[2]), str(val[3]))

res = a("35 age 6 ft")
print(res)
```

There are many other way too :-)

Comment: What if the input is not 4 items?

Comment: @Guy Read my comment properly. I said "you can try this." :-)

Comment: @Guy and also mentioned ```There are many other way too :-)```

Comment: Writing *you can try this* and *There are many other way too* doesn't mean you are not expected to give a good answer.

Comment: Thanks,

what if the first number can be an int or float, is there a way to just return the first 'number'

Comment: @NewPythonCoder Check the updated solution :-)

Comment: @NewPythonCoder Does this solve your problem?